# How to loop through each Post in Rails while changing the class each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to loop through each Post in a Rails app where the class changes each time. Here's the layout in HTML, how would I create this in a rails <% @posts.each do |post| %> loop. The css classes go from style1 to style 6

```
  <article class="style1">
    <span class="image">
      <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" />
    </span>
    <a href="generic.html">
      <h2>Magna</h2>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Sed nisl arcu euismod sit amet nisi lorem etiam dolor veroeros et feugiat.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
  <article class="style2">
    <span class="image">
      <img src="images/pic02.jpg" alt="" />
    </span>
    <a href="generic.html">
      <h2>Lorem</h2>
      <div class="content">
        <p>Sed nisl arcu euismod sit amet nisi lorem etiam dolor veroeros et feugiat.</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </article>
```

etc...

Answer (score 5):

You can use `each_with_index` something like:

```
- @posts.each_with_index do |post, i|
  %article{class: "style#{(i % 6) + 1}"}
    %span.image
      ...
```

Sorry, that's in HAML instead of ERB. I don't use ERB anymore and have forgotten how it goes. But, hopefully that gives you a feel for how to use the `each_with_index`. You can read more in the [docs](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator/each_with_index).

ERB Example:

```
<%- @posts.each_with_index do |post, i| %>
  <article class="style<%= (i % 6) + 1 %>">
    <span class="image">
      ...
    </span>
 </article>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Edited to add an ERB example

Comment: This is not the Rails way for doing this. There is the cycle helper.

Comment: Seems a little arcane. But, yeah. Ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can also modify yours CSS selectors instead:

```
article:nth-child(6n + 1){ color: peachpuff; }
article:nth-child(6n + 2){ color: deepskyblue; }
article:nth-child(6n + 3){ color: dimgray; }
article:nth-child(6n + 4){ color: forestgreen; }
article:nth-child(6n + 5){ color: gold; }
article:nth-child(6n + 6){ color: coral; }
```

Explanation here: https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/

Example here: https://codepen.io/alex3o0/pen/rzwwqm

Answer (score 0):

You are seaching for the cycle helper.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= content_tag :div, class: cycle('style1', 'style2', 'style3') do %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You can find more info here: https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper/cycle